# How we can prove that if $p,q$ be prime and $q\mid a^p-1$, then $q\mid a-1$ or $q=2kp+1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

As an elementary number theory question I tried to prove that if $p,q$ be prime and $q\mid a^p-1$, then $q\mid a-1$ or $q=2kp+1$?

I tried to solve this question but I stuck

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Case $a=2$ is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2553963/prove-that-if-q-2p-1-then-q-mid-2q-1-1-and-q-12kp)

Answer (score -1):

**Hint** By Fermat Little Theorem
$$
a^{q-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{q}
$$
You also know that
$$
a^p \equiv 1 \pmod{q}
$$
Let $d =\mbox{gcd}(p,q-1)$. Show that $a^{d} \equiv 1 \pmod{q}$.

Finally $d|p$ and $p$ is prime, you only have 2 choices for $d$. Discuss both.

Comment: Please strive not to add more dupe answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy changes [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).